# How do I run my GUI application created using Quickly via command line?

Tags: command-line, quickly

I have created an application using Quickly, packaged it and then installed it on my machine. How do I run it using the command line? Is there a one-word command for my application as in the command 'gedit' opens the a gedit window. If not, how do I define a one word command for my application such that it takes effect when a user installs it. Thanks!

Comment: did you create a .desktop file?

Comment: .desktop file can be created by the user after installation of the application. I want to automate this process so that the user just installs the application and a command line keyword gets defined for the application automatically.

Comment: Huh? "Me no understand any more".  Please [edit] your question and flesh it out a bit (beginning *why* you don't want a .desktop file created and what you're trying to accomplish)